# Doubly linked list, problems with tail

Tags: c++, list, double

I am working with doubly linked lists, and I am having trouble trying to solve one of many problems that I have already solved.

```
double linked_list::pop_back()
{
    double value = tail->value;
    if (size() == 1)
    {
        delete tail;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node_t * temp = tail->prev;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        delete tail;
        tail = temp;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The error I get is that `tail` is `nullptr` but it isn't supposed to be, since my `push_back()` function is working correctly.

```
void linked_list::push_back(double value) {
    node_t * n = new node_t(value);
    n->value = value;

    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = n; 
    }
    if (tail != nullptr) {
        tail->next = n;
    }
    n->next = nullptr;
    n->prev = tail;
    tail = n;
}
```

The error I get:

[image]

For the record, I have started `head` and `tail` at 0 when I create the struct.

Comment: Your tail has to be null in that example you posted then. There is no other way `tail->value` would give you a null pointer exception. Also, can you provide the main function you're using to test this? We can't run and compile based on what you provided here, which means less people can try to help you.

Comment: I won't downvote this time, but do not post pictures of text-output, instead post the text itself. The relevant error text would take at most `128-bytes` to store, but instead your image requires nearly `60,000-bytes`. Learn how to use your IDE to get text error output.

Comment: *but it isn't supposed to be* -- The program does exactly as you wrote.  If it doesn't behave the way you think it should, then you should be debugging the code instead of making assumptions such as the following -- *since my push_back() function is working correctly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several logic flaws in your `pop_back()`:

- You are not checking if `tail` is valid before reading from `tail->value`.  When `size() == 0`, `tail` will be `nullptr` (you can even see in your screenshot that `tail` is `"0x00000000 <NULL>"` when the error happens).
- You are not checking if `temp` is valid before updating `temp->next`.  When `size() == 1`, `temp` will be `nullptr` since `tail` is pointing at the only node in the list.
- You are not updating `head` at all.  When `size() == 1`, `head` and `tail` will be pointing at the same node, so `delete`'ing that node will leave `head` invalid if you don't update it (you can also see in your screenshot that `head->next` and `head->prev` are both invalid - `0xdddddddd` - which also shows that you are not managing your nodes correctly).

Try something more like this instead:

```
double linked_list::pop_back()
{
    // if the list is empty, return whatever you want, but it
    // would be better to throw an exception instead, since
    // there is nothing to pop ...
    if (!tail)
        return 0.0;

    node_t *n = tail;
    double value = n->value;

    if (n->prev)
        n->prev->next = nullptr;
    else
        head = nullptr;

    tail = n->prev;
    delete n;

    return value;
}
```